# What's the use of the __RequestVerificationToken?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a .NET C# MVC application with some forms in it which works fine. Now we also have an ASP Classic vbscript page that needed to interact with these forms, but using a regular post we got an error saying the __RequestVerificationToken wasn't set.

So we request the page and then store the token from the hidden input and the cookie in a variable and send it a long with the POST request. And it works.

But seeing its so simple to bypass it, whats the use of it anyway? It offers hardly any protection.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

this is an anti forgery token (prevent CSRF attack). It guarantees that the poster is the one who gets the form.

It prevents from anybody to forge a link and have it activated by a powered user.

Comment: Yes, that would work on GET request. Then its usefull to have these things in place so they can't hide a link in like an image. But since this is a POST request, the attacker can't simply use a link somewhere on a form. He needs javascript or a regular form he can control. And if has access to that, he can also request the token on behalf of the user and use it.

Comment: @HugoDelsing : by reading [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) we learn how ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute works. But imho without authentication (that is authorization filter) the token is useless as you point in your post. Authentication prevents attacker to get a valid token.

Comment: @tschmit007 in a CSRF attack, the attacker does not need to lay hands on the token. the token (as well as the authentication cookie) are only transferred between the victim and the web server. The trick is to tempt the victim to issue a post (which may look like a clicking on link, by means of a hidden form a javascript) and misuse their authorization to achieve something the victim didn't intend to do.