# is necessary to use __RequestVerificationToken in ajax post without form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm using ajax to post data to controller without html form tag. Now I want to know that is necessary using __RequestVerificationToken? and When should we use __RequestVerificationToken

```html
<i id="getreadnot" class="fa fa-users"></i>
<script>
$('#getreadnot').click(function () {
    let Url = '/Admin/Home/Notification';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: Url,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
});
</script>
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public string Notification()
    {
        return db.SiteInfos.Where(s => s.id == "Notifications").Select(s => s.value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use of the \_\_RequestVerificationToken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051456/whats-the-use-of-the-requestverificationtoken)

Answer (score -1):

Hi my friend I think is not necessary