# While doing concurrency testing for n different users,action requiring authentication executes before login in jmeter

Tags: concurrency, jmeter

I want 100 concurrent users to hit 
login
Action1
Action2
Action3
logout.

I created csv with 100 concurrent users.
Threadcount=100
Rampup=1
Loop is Forever
But when I execute the script for most of the time for Action1 I get login page in response. I believe it gets executed before login. 
Can somebody please help.
It is siteinfinity application.

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down so if you have `login` sampler before `action1` the login will always be executed first.

The reason of seeing the login page instead of `action1` response is that your `login` request fails somewhere somehow

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Check your sitefinity [security module settings](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/web-security-module), most probably you need to pass a special request parameter i.e. [__RequestVerificationToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051456/whats-the-use-of-the-requestverificationtoken) or something like this which needs to be extracted from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and added to the next request. Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/) article for comprehensive information and solution
3. You might want to add [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to introduce custom pass/fail criteria, i.e. to check presence of `Welcome` text or absence of login button, this way you will get confidence that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing and you're not getting "false positive" results